# JavaScript resources on the Stack Overflow site

Tags: bug, javascript

On my machine ([Fedora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29) 25, Firefox 56.0) I got the error shown below. Suggestions?

I can't log in through Google because of this.

[image]

Comment: Do you use [No Script](https://noscript.net/) extension or anything that might block Javascript code from running?

Comment: And/or do you have entries in the [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))?

Comment: Related: *[Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208)?*. It contains input for JavaScript whitelisting, cookies, etc. Especially near *"The following sites should be accessible"*.